# Bitmap with alpha channel crashes Bitmap () constructor only under Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, bitmap, alpha

Ran into a weird Bitmap problem that I can't find in Google:

The Bitmap constructor crashes on a file with an alpha channel under Windows 7, but works perfectly under Windows XP.

The code couldn't be simpler:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap (fname);
```

The error is: "Parameter is not valid", and there's no inner exception.

If it failed in Windows XP too, I'd suspect a simple bug, but since it works there it implies it's something more complex.

Any ideas how a bitmap with an alpha channel can be loaded under Windows 7? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: The .NET Bitmap class seems to fail reading a CMYK TIFF file with an alpha channel under Windows 7, 64-bit. The workaround is to use an Aurigma Bitmap, which (unlike a .NET Bitmap) can handle CMYK images with or without an alpha channel.

The Aurigma Bitmap is available from www.aurigma.com , and is compatible with .NET.

Comment: TIFF == Thousands of Incompatible File Formats.  Lots of tweaks and fixes in GDI+ version 1.10, XP has version 1.00